# Read oracle dump file (.dmp) file to panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I have one `testdata.dmp` available in AWS s3 bucket and want to load data into panda `dataframe`. Looking for some solution, I've `boto3` installed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nimgwfc , I have created python object using -> obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file). And the output of obj is returning -> 'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream'. But I want to load this data into panda dataframe. Basically my requirement is to convert .dmp and .bak file into .parquet in AWS s3 bucket using Lambda Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Your Oracle dump file `testdata.dmp` has a proprietary binary format maintained by Oracle. This means that Oracle controls which tools can process it correctly. One of such tools is [Oracle Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-datapump-import-utility.html).

A workflow to extract data from a Oracle dump file and write it as Parquet files (readable with Pandas) could look as follows:

1. Create an Oracle DB. As you are already using AWS S3, I suggest setting up an AWS [RDS instance with Oracle engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html).
2. Download `testdata.dmp` from S3 to the created Oracle DB. This can be done by [RDS' S3 integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html#oracle-s3-integration.using.download).
3. Run Oracle Data Pump Import on the RDS instance. This tool is installed by default. The RDS docs provide a [detailed walk-through](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPump.html). Now the content of `testdata.dmp` lives as tables with data and other objects inside the Oracle DB.
4. Dump all tables (and other objects) with a tool that is able to query Oracle DBs and able to write the result as Parquet. Some choices:

   - [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html) (Hadoop-based command line tool, but deprecated)
   - (Py)[Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) (Popular data processing tool and imho the unofficial successor of Sqoop.)
   - [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) + Pandas